# When I try to import an Excel spreadsheet in SQL I get an error

Tags: c#, sql, excel

Below is my code, any help will be greatly appreciated

> :The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'Breach'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.

```
public void importdatafromexcel(string excelfilepath)
{
    string ssqltable = "Testing";

    string myexceldataquery = "select [Case Owner],[Case Number],[Severity] from [Breach]";
    try
    {
        string sexcelconnectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelfilepath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
        string ssqlconnectionstring = "Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=0Breach;server= CHAUDAHARI-J1-W\\SQLEXPRESS";

        string sclearsql = "delete from " + ssqltable;
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(ssqlconnectionstring);
        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(sclearsql, sqlconn);
        sqlconn.Open();
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlconn.Close();

        OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(sexcelconnectionstring);
        OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand(myexceldataquery, oledbconn);
        oledbconn.Open();
        OleDbDataReader dr = oledbcmd.ExecuteReader();
        SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ssqlconnectionstring);
        bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = ssqltable;
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);
        }

        oledbconn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        txtProcessingStatus.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select [Case Owner],[Case Number],[Severity] from [Breach]
```

Is there a worksheet named "Breach" in the Excel file you are opening?  In your statement above, I believe [Breach] should be the name of the worksheet you are looking for in the Excel file you are opening.